# How to change location of Rails compiled assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm working on integrating a javascript library into the rails asset pipe line.

The javascript expects a `fonts/` and `images/` folder to be available at the root level, but I think Rails is precompiling these to `assets/fonts/` and `assets/images`.

The reason I think this is the case is because if I put the `fonts` and `images` folder directly into the `public` folder everything works.

But if I place `fonts` and `images` in the `apps/assets/fonts` and `apps/assets/images` the javascript returns 404 errors for the requested fonts and images.

Is there somewhere in Rails config that I can tell Rails to precompile these fonts and images folders to `public/` instead of `public/assets/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the asset pipeline helpers in your case, especially because of the fingerprinting strings that will be appended to the name of the assets.

to do that:

1.change the references to the font/image files to

using the [asset helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/asset_path)

```
<%= asset_path 'fontFileNameAndExtension' %>
```

using [asset image helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path)

```
<%= image_path 'imageFileNameAndExtension' %>
```

2.change the extension of your `.js` file to `.js.erb`

3.include the name of your `js` file into `application.js` as

```
//= require YourJsFileName
```

4.execute the pre-compile again, and you might want to clean the compiled assets first:

```
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: This doesn't address how the javascript library will know to look in `assets/fonts` or `assets/images` instead of the `fonts` or `images` locations it is expecting. That's the whole issue leading to the question I think.

Comment: I advise you to test it Shadwell, by using the asset helpers, rails 4+ will build links to the files present in `fonts` and `images` folders as described in my answer. I use it like that all the time =)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Worth pointing out though I think as that is the root of the original problem.